# Rails calculate and set a field value in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an event table that contains start_at and ends_at.  It also have a boolean for allday.

If the event is allday, then the user enters a field called hours.  But, if they enter the start_at and ends_at, I'ld like to calculate and save in the hours field.

In English (not Ruby):

```
If event.allday = > true
  hours = ends_at - starts_at
```

This way, I wouldn't have to calculate it during all the different display pages I have and it would be easier to sum.

OR - would this logic go into the model?

Thanks!

UPDATE-----------

I tried putting this into the model:

```
  before_save :calculate_hours

  def calculate_hours
    if self.allday != true
      self.hours = ((self.ends_at - self.starts_at)/ 3600).to_f.round(2)
    end
 end
```

Comment: This likely belongs in the model, yes. But why would a user want to enter hours for something flagged as "all day". It seems backwards.

Comment: It's using allday from Fullcalendar.  The hours are for work performed without specifying the start and stop time. Or they can put in the start and stop times, and the app should calculate the hours.

Comment: You're right it's backwards - need to test for not allday. !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Business logic always belongs in the model.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_hours

  private
    def set_hours
      if allday?
        self.hours = ends_at - starts_at
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: How come ends_at and starts_at don't need self.  in front of them?  Why before validation instead of before save?  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I've had issues when trying to set values in a `before_save` but now that I think about it it may have been when dealing with associated objects.  `before_save` would probably work here as well.  You only need the `self.{attribute_name}` when setting the value using `=`... It's just how Ruby works.  Without the `self` there it'd set a local variable named `hours`, but not the actual database record value.  Getting the values `ends_at` and `starts_at` would only need `self` if there were local variables defined with the same name and you had to differentiate between them (don't do this)